# Prevent pages form automatically linking to email addresses and urls

Tags: pages

Is there a way to prevent pages from automatically turning anything that looks like an email address or a url into a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the menu found at "Edit" > "Substitutions" > "Smart Links" and you can edit automatic hyperlinking.

More information can be found in the [Apple knowledge base](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23916198#23916198).